# JSON.parse is giving "Unexpected token \u000f in JSON at position 129"

Tags: node.js, aes, sha1

I am just encrypting json with sha1 it is showing error.

I have tried this.

```
console.log("decrypt===>"+(decrypt.trim()));

let decrypt_hash = sha1((JSON.parse(decrypt)));

decrypt===>{"deviceserialno":"test123","devicetype":"mobile","devicemodel":"test12","deviceversion":"1.0","devicemfg":"1","osversion":"1.0"}
```

The above is decrypt.

Comment: You are having SHIFT IN character at position 129

Comment: @kzrfaisal what is the solution?

Comment: added an answer below. would you refer to it?

Comment: did'nt worked! @AliD.

Comment: share your console.log details

Comment: decrypt===>{"deviceserialno":"test123","devicetype":"mobile","devicemodel":"test12","deviceversion":"1.0","devicemfg":"1","osversion":"1.0"}